# Run PHP File In Terminal/Powershell without .php extension

Tags: php, command-line-interface, php-7

I've seen numerous posts of running php files without extensions on the browser.My question is,is it possible to do the same when running a file in cli?Example scenario:I have a file called Test.php
that contains this simple code:

```php
class Test 
{
    public function action()
    {
        global $argv;
        $script = array_shift($argv);

        print($argv[0]);
    }
}
(new Test)->action();
```

Now on the terminal,instead of doing

```
$ php Test.php -calltoAction
```

I'd like to do:

```sh
$ php Test -calltoAction
```

and get **calltoAction** printed out.How do I accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible. PHP CLI does not care about the file extensions.

Trying to pass argv to your function as a global is not the way to go. Pass it as a function argument instead.

```
class Test
{
    public function action($args)
    {
        $script = array_shift($args);

        print($args[0]);
    }
}
(new Test)->action($argv);
```

~

Comment: I get this error when I call it without extension: **Could not open input file: Test**

Comment: Rename Test.php to Test. `mv Test.php Test`

Comment: Ok thanks..that worked..follow up question.Are there serious security implications of omitting the file extension?

Comment: None that I can think of.

Comment: This does not seem like a good practice to me. There is value in knowing that a file has a certain type of content. Long term you will confuse yourself and others who have to maintain this code.

Comment: no,I figured it's not.I was just trying to recreate laravel's artisan..Im new to cli scripting.just wanted to easy how complex it was